# Jenkins and Docker git checked in files and node binary

Tags: git, docker, jenkins

I am attempting to contain a Jenkins server using docker. I originally installed Jenkins on a Digital Ocean droplet, I went into the server and used `scp` to pull down everything from the Jenkins directory. I am mounting this volume locally with `docker-compose`.

My main concern is keeping this Jenkins directory backed up in git but only the necessary files.

When my first job was run it installed node:

```
unpacking https://nodejs.org/dist/v9.11.1/node-v9.11.1-linux-x64.tar.gz to /var/jenkins_home/tools/jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation/static_node_9.11. on Jenkins
```

I am wondering how I am going to maintain this Jenkins volume in git? What do I ignore? It seems I want to ignore `tools`. How can I have docker install this file for me so that the first job doesn't need to download it?

```
version: '3'

services:
  jenkins:
    # image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    build: ./jenkins
    ports:
      - "3001:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/jenkins:/var/jenkins_home
```

This question could be simply boiled down to:

What does a .gitignore look like for the jenkins dir?

```
plugins
.nvm
.npm
tools
workspace
workflow-libs
updates
logs
.standard-cache
.groovy
.cache
.java
.nano
jobs*builds
```